# XSD validation of XML node that could be simple or could be complex

Tags: xml, powershell, xsd-validation

Given an XML node that can be either

```
<Uninstall id="Text">{GUID}</Uninstall>
```

or

```
<Uninstall id="Text">
    <File>PATH TO EXECUTABLE</File>
    <Arguments>ARGUMENTS</Arguments>
</Uninstall>
```

I am trying to validate this with XSD. I have this

```
<xs:complexType name = 'Uninstall'>
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base='xs:string'>
                <xs:attributeGroup ref='Task_Attributes'/>
                <xs:attributeGroup ref='Directive_Attributes'/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name = 'File' type='xs:string' minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs='1' />
                <xs:element name = 'Arguments' type='xs:string' minOccurs = '0' maxOccurs='1' />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attributeGroup ref='Task_Attributes'/>
            <xs:attributeGroup ref='Directive_Attributes'/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

But that errors with `Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:simpleContent' element is not supported in this context."` when I add the schema file to the `[xml.xmlReaderSettings]`. Note that the two attributeGroups reference the possible attributes, which are the same for both the simple and complex form. So I am pretty sure the issue I am having is with doing a choice between simple and complex. But maybe I can also simplify the XSD to only reference the attributes once, since that's common?

I know the XML is pretty ugly, and I am moving to a more consistent XML structure. But I need to validate the current inconsistent XML to automate migration to the new, more consistent XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSD is not capable of expressing every conceivable constraint on your data, and that's especially true with XSD 1.0 - assertions in XSD 1.1 give you a lot more flexibility. But this one is awkward even in XSD 1.1.

One option that's sometimes overlooked is to define your schema against a cleaned up version of the structure, and then transform the actual instance to this structure prior to validation. For example if one form of the `Uninstall` element is deprecated and retained only for compatibility, you could transform the input to convert deprecated forms to their target form prior before doing XSD validation on the result.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Unfortunately neither approach is deprecated currently, and both are being migrated to a new structure that in standardized. The current mess is larger than just this example, and comes from functionality creep over a number of years. Looks like I will be doing some of my validation with Powershell, which is fine.